# change z-index with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making a website in php

i make left menu like this

[image]

these menu coming from database in one string.
i am printing it with echo.
i use image as a background to each menu.

now i want like this

[image]

i have a arrow image.

i know i can do it with z-index. but i cant do it with only css.
so i need a help to do it with javascript.
i want to change the html using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an all CSS solution try to building your menu like this...

```
<style type="text/css">
  .menu li {
    background:url(path/to/gradient.png) top left repeat-x;
  }
  .menu li a {
    display:block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    backround:url(path/to/arrow.png) bottom right no-repeat;
  }
</style>


<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="fanclub.php">Fan Club</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="poll.php">Poll</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you must do your solution in JavaScript (which I suggest you avoid) you can access the z-index property of any element (that supports it) like so:

```
// DOM Scripting Example (Single Element)
myElement.style.zIndex = 1000;

// jQuery Example (All elements with the "arrow" class)
$('.arrow').css('z-index', 1000);
```

Comment: i would suggest an unordered list for your menu though. since it is technically a list of navigation links :)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myselectorclass').css('z-index','1000');
});
```

Replace '1000' with your desired z-index value, of course